# onblur on input field makes popup unclickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, onblur

```js
    function showSuggestions(){
        let searchableModulesDiv = document.getElementById('searchableModules');
        searchableModulesDiv.classList.remove('d-none');
    }

    function hideSuggestions(){
        let searchableModulesDiv = document.getElementById('searchableModules');
        searchableModulesDiv.classList.add('d-none');
    }
    
    function filterSuggestions() {
        
    }
```

```css
.prj-searchable-modules{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: 70px;
    z-index: 2;
    width:100%;
}

.d-none {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="searchBar" class="w-100 d-inline-flex">
    <!-- ... icons, labels, etc -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Module search..."
           onfocus="showSuggestions();" onblur="hideSuggestions();" onkeyup="filterSuggestions();">
</form>

<div id="searchableModules" class="card shadow-sm border-secondary rounded-3 prj-searchable-modules d-none">
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item text-start">
      <a class="nav-link" href="calendar.html">
        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-fw"></i><span class="ps-3">Calendar</span></a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... more li items -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have a quick search bar in my website which when clicked shows a list clicable links.

The problem I'm facing is that clicking a link does nothing, and that's because I think the search bar loses focus as soon as I click the link, and so the actual "click" happens after the link already disappeared.

Any suggestion is appreciated, even if it's a different approach (possibly without using external plugins).

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and plain JS at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` to postpone the hiding after the click event. Also, if you do not want to hide the list if an item is clicked, then you could simply add a conditional for the blur.

```js
function showSuggestions(){
        let searchableModulesDiv = document.getElementById('searchableModules');
        searchableModulesDiv.classList.remove('d-none');
    }

    function hideSuggestions(){
        setTimeout(() => {
            let searchableModulesDiv = document.getElementById('searchableModules');
            searchableModulesDiv.classList.add('d-none');
        }, 100);
    }
    
    function filterSuggestions() {
        
    }
```

```css
.prj-searchable-modules{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: 70px;
    z-index: 2;
    width:100%;
}

div.d-none > #searchableModules {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="searchBar" class="w-100 d-inline-flex">
    <!-- ... icons, labels, etc -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="Module search..."
           onfocus="showSuggestions();" onblur="hideSuggestions();" onkeyup="filterSuggestions();">
</form>

<div id="searchableModules" class="card shadow-sm border-secondary rounded-3 prj-searchable-modules" onclick="console.log('clicked'); hideSuggestions();">
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item text-start">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-fw"></i><span class="ps-3">Calendar</span></a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... more li items -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, very easy solution I could immediately implement. I've tried with a timeout of 100 and it still does nothing, but increasing it to 500 made it work. Could this potentially create issues?

Comment: @GiLA3 we can never exclude the possibility of meeting issues in the future. The idea that we need to apply is to test everything possible in every major browser, trying to break it. If you do not manage in breaking it, then it works. You could also have a CSS animation while the list is disappearing. If you encounter problems, then you will have to switch to an alternative or adjust. Luckily, adjustments are probably possible to whatever issue you may find, but if you really need to switch to another solution, then there are alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the search bar and search modules in the same parent-element, you can just use CSS.

```
.search-ctr:focus-within #searchableModules {
    display:block;
}

#searchableModules {
    display: none;
}

<div class='search-ctr'>
    <form id="searchBar" class="w-100 d-inline-flex">
    <!-- ... icons, labels, etc -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput"        placeholder="Module search..."
           onfocus="showSuggestions();" onblur="hideSuggestions();" onkeyup="filterSuggestions();">
</form>

<div id="searchableModules" class="card shadow-sm border-secondary rounded-3 prj-searchable-modules d-none">
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item text-start">
      <a class="nav-link" href="calendar.html">
        <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-fw"></i><span class="ps-3">Calendar</span></a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... more li items -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I've saw that solution somewhere in my research but for some reason it didn't work for my case. I had a <div class="card"> already wrapping the two elements but adding your search-ctr class didn't produce the intended behavior